# Imageview place at center on click in GallaryView layout

Tags: android

I am using `GalleryView` layout in which have multiple `ImageView`. When i click on `ImageView` that view comes on horizontally center position of device. Is there any way to stop this, means view will not come on center on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default Android Galery is center Locked, So if you need it to be left locked.
Fork the code here at https://github.com/TheLevelUp/android-left-locked-gallery